# Function to redraw Bitmap on Sprite without passing in said Bitmap?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, graphics, bitmapdata

If I have a `BitmapData` that's already been drawn onto a `Sprite`. Is there a way to redraw the `BitmapData` onto a Sprites `Graphics` object without having to invoke `beginBitmapFill` and passing in the same `BitmapData`?

Comment: cloning the bitmapData is an intensive process. the beginBitmapFill method uses a reference to the bitmapData ( not a clone ). could you tell us more about what you intend to do ?

Comment: Redrawing my Sprites when moving them with `drag()` is fixing a lot of problems. But I need to redraw Sprites that I drew calling `beginBitmapFill`. I wasn't really explicit enough letting you guys know that I had drawn it somewhere else in my code. At this point, I think I'm just going to implement a simple static BitmapData cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may clone the image.

See the example:
http://www.webverwirklichung.com/en/blog/programming/flex/clone-image-flex-flashdisplayloader